# shim: transport is closing error

Tags: macos, hyperledger, docker-toolbox, hyperledger-fabric

Exact same error as mentioned in jira ticket https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-246 .

Although one of the comment says to take everything latest but that didn't helped me.

**My fabric env:** running within docker toolbox for mac with **docker-compose.yaml** as mentioned below.

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  command: membersrvc
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
  links:
    - membersrvc
  command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
```

And I was registering my chaincode by using below command.

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:50250 ./chaincode_example02
```

I got the peer port as **50250** by running below command.

```
netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"
```

Comment: go version: **go1.7 darwin/amd64**. Any relation to go vesion ?

Comment: can you try `172.17.0.2:50250` or `172.17.0.1:50250` instead of `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: and please confirm the port number assigned from your `VagrantFile` as well